# How to give static name to embeded JavaScript File as a Resource in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to add java script file as a embedded resource file and i followed instructions mentioned in [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4)

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("SampleControl.UpdatePanelAnimation.js", "application/x-javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)]
```

Once the file is generated in HTML file display this added javascript file as follows:

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=lyBGZNf7CGO603CCJNN8yTrjkoAldyy52iy559T1liheYL57VNFeGimuj8ohz4WEtG3M7F5mpO883thOOPBBT8UuRhleAeRuCd6qODUlQGDXzJGW4TK9TYCIXV9igRZ2M5X_-hyrlo8u3Dz5IHY-Pg2&amp;t=60342d3a" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Instead of this dynamically generated name i need to add name something like this.

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=UpdatePanelAnimation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can i do this?

**EDIT:**
My java script file is in separate project

Answer (score 2):

you can use scriptmanager to create your own refernece in this manner:

```
<asp:scriptmanager runat="server">
    <scripts>
        <asp:scriptreference name="WebForms.js" assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" path="~/1.js">
        <asp:scriptreference name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" path="~/3.js">
        <asp:scriptreference name="MicrosoftAjax.js" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" path="~/4.js">
    </asp:scriptreference></asp:scriptreference></asp:scriptreference></scripts>
```

this will give HTML like this:

```
<script src="/DeAXDify/ScriptResource.axd?d=etBSwiV14lSQ0YmAEYFkRsEWCxZgNT44ZlBMp0-JG80D6vYrSWRwH-xgjsikUbq5SId1HBi_Zo1MRBZ--Iho5A2&t=1761aa8f" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you may find more info here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx

Comment: my java script is in separate project. so i can't give path like this.